# timer.performWithDelay doesn't work properly

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have the following code:

```
local function RemovePlayer()
    print("Something")
end

function change(e)
    if(e.phase=="began")then
        Player.alpha=1
        Player.height=50
        Player.width=50
    end
    if(e.phase=="moved")then
    angle=(math.atan2( (e.y - Player.y), (e.x - Player.x))*180)/math.pi +90
    Player.rotation=angle
    end
    if(e.phase=="ended")then
        transition.to(Player,{time=200,height=32,width=32})
        local xx = (e.x-Player.x)*2
        local yy = (e.y-Player.y)*2
        Player.bodyType = "dynamic"
        Player:applyForce( xx, yy, Player.x, Player.y )
        timer.performWithDelay ( 10000,RemovePlayer() )
    end

return true
end
```

The problem is that `timer.performWithDelay` doesn't seem to work correct because the "Something" is printed in the console immediately after the ended phase and not with 10000 delay. Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening maybe because:

1. Your timer will first execute the function; then execute it again after 10000 milliseconds have passed. Thus, you get the output instantaneously.

   If you want to have the user wait for 10s; use `os.sleep( 10 )`.
2. Another possible cause is that you are calling the function while declaring a timer. Change:

   ```
   timer.performWithDelay ( 10000,RemovePlayer() )
   ```

   to

   ```
   timer.performWithDelay ( 10000, RemovePlayer )  -- Notice no () here
   ```

Comment: i had the same problem and removing () fixed the issue! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your timer as below:

```
timer.performWithDelay ( 10000,RemovePlayer,1 ) 
-- 1 is the number of times that the 'RemovePlayer' function is to be called.
```

Keep coding......... :)

Comment: I tried that too but doesn't change something :( . Thanks for the advice anyway ;)

Comment: @AvraamMavridis: I've tried your above code and is perfectly working for me. So, just check whether you are calling RemovePlayer() directly in anywhere else in your code.